# windows-curses not installing using pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
python -m pip install windows-curses
```

gives

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for windows-curses
```

Comment: What is your operating system and python version? It looks like it is not matching the requirements. Please post the complete output you get from the command by copy-pasting it into your question and putting it in appropriate format(no screenshot)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you use `Windows`? Module [windows-curses](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/windows-curses), 
 is only for `Windows`. Other systems may use standard module [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) (which you don't have to install). Or try other modules:  
[unicurses](https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses#installing-unicurses), 
[Urwid](http://urwid.org/), 
[picotui](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui), 
[npyscreen](http://www.npcole.com/npyscreen/),  or nice looking
[textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual), 
[rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich)

Comment: My operating system is Mac. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The module is already installed as a package curses.

The problem is I am trying to install the package that already exists. I do not know the package exits in mac os because I'm new to mac.